Is there a way to add a reference to a gameobject during gametime?
I'm trying to make a game where you can make custom projectiles with various components that have special properties (like poison, explosions, anti-gravity, mind control).
Then you would be able to put that bullet in a gun.
I'm thinking of using OnCollisionEnter and a box collider to get the GameObject and then use a raycast that would get the gun script on a gun and change the projectile reference to the projectile in the box collider.
Before I actually try that though, I want to make sure I know how to assign a reference in game.
I've looked everywhere online and I have not been able to find any information on how to make a script that lets the player change the reference of a gameobject. My gun script currently works by instantiating a projectile prefab through a public gameobject reference.
Here are my current script for guns and projectiles, these are placeholders until I can better understand how to change variables and such in gametime and outside of the scene editor.
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 10f;
    private Rigidbody projectile;

    void Start()
    {
        projectile = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        projectile.AddForce(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}


public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform muzzle;
    public int magazineSize;
    public int bulletsInMag;
    public float reloadTime = 3;
    bool reloading = false;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && bulletsInMag > 0)
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        else if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && bulletsInMag <= 0 && !reloading))
        {
            Reload();
        }
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, muzzle.position, muzzle.rotation);
        bulletsInMag--;
    }

    private void Reload()
    {
        reloading = true;
        StartCoroutine(ReloadTime());
    }

    IEnumerator ReloadTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
        bulletsInMag = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
    }
}



yes, of course.. you have to build them a manner to select it, such as an inventory, hot keys, menus etc.. and then you code according to selection...

That doesn't answer my question, how do I reassign a gameobject mid game?
Or do I abandon trying to reassign variables and instead of the gun instantiate the child of some bullet holder object?

Its not clear what part you are unsure of.  To assign the reference you would just assign it eg. someGun.bullet = modifiedBullet;

Your question wasnt clear, as you show all the necessary ideas you'd need in code, so, it seemed a more hyperthetical than physical..

hijinxbassist, assume there are multiple bullets.

Your gun supports a single bullet, so if you for instance had multiple types of ammo, it would be whatever action you use to switch bullets would assign the same way.  eg.  myGun.bullet = selectedBullet;

None of these answers help me, should I just delete the question and figure it out on my own?

Try editing your question to better reflect the issue you are trying to solve.  The question posed was about assigning a reference to a variable.  If that is not the question, try restating the issue and where you are stuck.

That is the question, specifically the question is asking how to give the player the ability to assign a variable during gametime. Everyone here has only told me how to do it during the scene editor.

Do you mean in runtime right? You can use OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter to put myGun.bullet = selectedBullet; like @hijinxbassist said.  you can get selectedBullet from the collision param var selectedBullet = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Bullet>(); . So, everytime you colliding with collectable bullet object, your gun bullet will changed to the new bullet. is that what you ask?

Not quite, I want the bullet to be changed to whatever bullet is colliding with a bullet holder object, not the bullet colliding with the player.
